# An issue with Vlookup

Tags: vlookup, sumifs, libreoffice-calc

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZuJ7.jpg)

I want in B11 to sum up all `1`s (from CLIENT A) and in C11 the amount of appearance of CLIENT A (in this example four times). 
Same for CLIENT B in B12 and C12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter formula for B11 as `=SUMIF(A$2:A$8,"="&A11,B$2:B$8)`.  Then drag down to fill B12.

Enter formula for C11 as `=COUNTIF(A$2:A$8,"="&A11)`.  Then drag down to fill C12.

```
System    Counter All
~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~ ~~~
CLIENT A        2   4
CLIENT B        2   3
```

For some locales, use `;` instead of `,` as the formula delimiter.

Documentation: [SUMIF](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUMIF_function)
 and [COUNTIF](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_COUNTIF_function).

Comment: Oh boy, thank you very much. After hours over hours of trial and error, your Code gave exactly the same result as my attempts. I don't know what exactly was the failure, but after renaming the Client cells (in the original project they all have other names) it finally worked. Could have saved like 4 hours if I had done that earlier. Thank you anyways !

Comment: It sounds like this was helpful, so please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).